# What is the proper PHP syntax to post a file that exists in a directory that's on the server?

Tags: php, mysql, post

**This is a basic post form in PHP that loads from the client PC.  What is the proper syntax to load from a directory on the server?**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php?option=com_productionparse" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="90000000000" /><br />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="file" size=120 type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such syntax - HTML forms as the one you show are for client-side uploading only.

To build something that fetches a file from a remote location, you would have to put together a script in PHP. Such scripts already exist; you would have to explain what exactly you want to do for anybody to make a recommendation.

Comment: I use a PHP parser that uploads files from my laptop/PC.  I have a hunch it would be faster to upload via FTP and parse the file from the server.

Comment: You would have to have an entirely different script to do that (one to show you a selection of files in the FTP directory, and one to handle the selected file, and all that in a secure way.) MAybe you want to add that information into your question.

Comment: "I have a hunch it would be faster to upload via FTP " - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717200/comparing-http-and-ftp-for-transferring-files