# How do I upload multipart with Curl and PHP?

Tags: php, curl, upload, http-post, multipart

How do I upload a multipart with PHP and Curl? The first part is an XML, the other is a binary.

The particular API I try to use is the [Constant Contact image upload](http://community.constantcontact.com/t5/Documentation/Managing-Images/ba-p/25101).

I think I know how to do it with only one part, but how to post two parts?

Comment: There's a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568772/write-multiple-files-in-a-single-curl-request. It might answer your question too.

Comment: Have you find: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/multipartpost.html ?

Comment: Please pay attention to the '@' in front of the file you want to upload!

Comment: Exactly as @NarcisRadu said. This has hit me too in the past :X