# How to send array request via CURL

Tags: php, curl

I need file upload form like this

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="f[]">
<input type="file" name="f[]">
<input type="file" name="f[]">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

but in Curl.

The main problem is passing array of files with the same parameter name to build request like this:

```
-----boundary-2439bfe7wcbc74c8d36ef21e0c70583f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f[]"; filename="firstImage.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

...skipped...


-----boundary-2439bfe7wcbc74c8d36ef21e0c70583f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f[]"; filename="secondImage.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

...skipped...
```

I know about this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and I confused with this CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

I tried to pass array:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'f[]' => array('@/fil1.png',   '@/fil2.png'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
```

It didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568772/write-multiple-files-in-a-single-curl-request

Comment: Did you try this? $data = array('f' => array('@/fil1.png', '@/fil2.png', '@/fil3.png'));

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm trying to use it in combination with tmhOAuth to upload multiple images to twitter.