# PHP cURL post file and string same key

Tags: python, php, curl

I have a rest API with multiple file and string with same key.

I was test with python Requests => **successful**

Sample code:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/mms/campaign/create_static"

payload={'SentDate': '23-03-2022 09:15:00',
'Sender': 'Sender',
'Msg': 'MMS test.'}
files=[
  ('Msg',('image2.jpg',open('image2.jpg','rb'),'image/jpeg')),
  ('Msg',('image1.jpg',open('image1.jpg','rb'),'image/jpeg')),
  ('ListPhone',('csv_file.csv',open('csv_file.csv','rb'),'text/csv'))
]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic key=='
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

but main language use for my project is PHP

**How to post multiple file and string throw cURL of PHP or another way?**

This is sample code generate by Postman for php-cURL:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/mms/campaign/create_static',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
         'SentDate' => '23-03-2022 09:15:00',
         'Sender' => 'Sender',
         'Msg' => 'MMS test.',
         'Msg'=> new CURLFILE('image1.jpg'),
         'Msg'=> new CURLFILE('image2.jpg'),
         'ListPhone'=> new CURLFILE('csv_file.csv')
    ),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Basic key=='
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Sorry my english is not good

Thanks for all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write Multiple files in a single CURL request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568772/write-multiple-files-in-a-single-curl-request)

Comment: Problem solved by keywork multipart stream
[link](https://docs.php-http.org/en/latest/components/multipart-stream-builder.html)