# Saving images using php to different urls

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

In `php` my goal is to have a system whereby I want to save an instance of an image in different locations over different `URLS`.

**Example:**

```
Image 1 ; Image 2 ; Image 3
```

.

```
www.example.com ; www.example-image.com ; www.elpmaxe.com
```

Specific `image` should be saved across all the `URLS`.

I want to achieve this all through a single log in page where the admin can upload images and add the information they desire, perhaps different information for each site.

**Question:**

How would I achieve a central place whereby I can upload images to several URLS? If I had a site such as www.admin.com and that site can do all the upload functionality of the several sites? Tips and pointers helpful at this stage!

**Tools:**

PHP & mySQL

Comment: HAHA the question was too vague, I've updated it! I can understand how it will work but I can't understand the fact that the other sites will have to allow the access from that central site right? If not there can be no way to allow another site to just dump images on them.

Comment: I think this is a case of RTFM > http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Answer (score 2):

I think it's needles to say, you would need access (probably FTP access) to each of the servers.

What you want to look at is 
[CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

And I would suggest getting familiar with sending files over CURL: [Send file via cURL from form POST in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223977/send-file-via-curl-from-form-post-in-php)

I'm pretty sure you're familiar with how you're going to lay out your application logic.

Please let me know if you need more details or have any other questions.

**EDIT**
You could also look into [PHP FTP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)

Comment: haha yeah I have the ftp details, and the app logic, it was more the php code to use to enable me to dump files on different URLS. Is there any security issues to watch out for using cURL or php ftp?