# How to post files using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL for the first time. I have to send one image file and one audio file posted by the user.

My cURL code is working, but instead of an image file and an audio file my code is sending a .tmp file.

I googled it, but in every example I found they have used realpath of file directly.

I tried to find real path of the file, but I didn't find any solution. 
Here is my code block in which I am collecting all data in an array to pass it to cURL:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$image = $_POST['image']['name'];
$imagetmp = $_POST['image']['tmp_name'];
$imagesize = $_POST['image']['size'];
$imagepath = '@'.$imagetmp;

$audio = $_POST['audio']['name'];
$audiotmp = $_POST['audio']['tmp_name'];
$audiosize = $_POST['audio']['size'];
$audiopath = '@'.$audiotmp;

$data = array("name" => $name, "image"=> $imagepath, "audio" => $audiopath); //array to sned data using cURL

//my cURL code to post data
```

Where am I doing wrong? How to send files using cURL?

Comment: I don't really understand. Are you trying to send the file via cURL or the path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4270282/3445065 this guy explains the same scenario.

Comment: Improved formatting layout and grammar

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to post file data:

```
$filedata = file_get_contents('file_location/filename.jpg');    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $filedata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use file=@path with curl

```
curl -kiSs -X POST https://<domain>/path/to/api/files/ \
-F "param1=param2" \
-F "file=@/path/to/test.xlsx"  \
-H "Authorization":"bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsIn"

File successfully uploaded (test.xlsx!)
```

Comment: The `@` syntax was deprecated in PHP 5.6. In currently supported versions of PHP, you need to use the CurlFile class. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php