# send CURL data to IBM Watson for recognition

Tags: curl, ibm-watson

I'm trying to send an audio file for recognition to IBM Watson which is popularly used for speech to text conversion. I have followed the tutorial for the HTTP Rest interface where I discovered this :

```
curl -X POST -u {username}:{password}
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--data-binary @{path}audio-file.flac
```

"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"

This command is used for recognition of the audio file you are sending to watson.

And below here is my PHP code using cURL.

```
        <?php

               $ch = curl_init();

               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
                   "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to- 
                    text/api/v1/recognize");
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
               $post = array(
                      "file" => "@" .realpath("{path}audio-file.flac")
                       );
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{username}" . ":" . 
                                                       "{password}");

                $headers = array();
               $headers[] = "Content-Type: audio/flac";
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

               $result = curl_exec($ch);
              if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                                 echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
                                 }

             else{
                 print_r($result);
                 }
              curl_close ($ch);

               ?>
```

When I run this in browser, I keep getting this error:

```
{ "code" : 401 , "error" : "Not Authorized" , "description" : "2018-05-03T03:15:09-05:00, Error ERCDPLTFRM-INVLDCHR occurred when accessing https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize, Tran-Id: stream01-896101253 - " }
```

The expected output should be:

```
{
        "results": [
        {
             "alternatives": [
             {
                "confidence": 0.891,
                "transcript": "several tornadoes touch down as a line 
                 of severe thunderstorms swept through Colorado on 
                 Sunday "

             }
            ],
            "final": true
          }
        ],
       "result_index": 0
       }
```

I don't understand what to do in order to rectify the mistake. Is the binary data field correct? The one below:

```
          $post = array(
                 "file" => "@" .realpath("{path}audio-file.flac")
          );
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

or there is some other problem...

[Note:]

I have successfully rectified the problem of authentication by providing a valid username and password. But now the problem seems to be different. Some of the modifications in my code below:

```
        $post = array(
                  "file" => 
           curl_file_create('<tmp_path>','file_type','file_name')
                   );

       $headers[] = "Content-Type: audio/mp3";
```

These modifications are made as my audio file is mp3 extended. But now while running the script on browser, I get:

{ "code_description": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "error": "Stream was 0 bytes but needs to be at least 100 bytes." }

I have checked a relevant post regarding this error:400 problem but still the problem persists. This was the link [Send file via cURL from form POST in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223977/send-file-via-curl-from-form-post-in-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Even after following the answers in the above link, my problem does not go.

But when the run the following in terminal as :

curl -X POST -u {some_username}:{some_password} --header "Content-Type: audio/mp3" --data-binary @/var/www/test/96_-_Cliches.mp3 "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"

It is perfectly fetching the output as expected. But when running the php script on browser, I get this problem. What could have possibly went wrong? Please suggest what to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue!! This was the part below which was responsible for the problem...

```
$post = array(
              "file" => 
       curl_file_create('<tmp_path>','file_type','file_name')
               );
```

I have to add some codes to my php file which were...

```
$data = file_get_contents(<temp_file_path>);
```

The tmp_file_path comes from ..

```
 $tmpfile = $_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'];(When you are using form to upload the audio and send to Watson server)
```

Some other lines were also added...

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: audio/mp3']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Then are executing the code in browser, the result was perfect as expected
like this below:

```
    {
      "results": [
       {
             "alternatives": [
              {
                 "confidence": 0.891,
                 "transcript": "several tornadoes touch down as a line 
             of severe thunderstorms swept through Colorado on Sunday 
                "
              }
             ],
         "final": true
         }
        ],
        "result_index": 0
       }
```

Well all taken care of :D!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. I Just want to share code that works for me (18/08/2022).

It works fine, just copy-paste and hit refresh your browser.

---

```
$fname = 'YourFilePath';  //Example: 'C:/audios/audio-file.flac;
$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath($fname));
$file = array ('file' => $cfile); 

$urlx = 'Paste here your url'; //It is something like this: https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/xxxxxxxxxxx
$curlx = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_URL, $urlx);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:PASTE_EXACTLY_HERE_YOUR_API_KEY'); 
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: audio/flac']); 
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, 40000);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
  
$datax = curl_exec($curlx);
curl_close($curlx);
print($datax);
```