# Replicate CURL multipart/form-data request with Guzzle / League OAuth2 Client

Tags: oauth-2.0, guzzle

I am attempting to replicate a CURL POST request in Guzzle, but Guzzle request is failing.

This is the CURL request that works successfully:

```
$file = new \CURLFile( $document );
$file->setPostFilename( basename( $document ) );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken,
                "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
            ] );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [ 'fileData' => $file ] );

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

And here is what I am currently using for the Guzzle request but it does not work:

```
$options['multipart'][] = [
    'name'      => 'fileData',
    'contents'  => fopen( $document, 'r' ),
    'filename'  => basename( $document ),
];

$request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest( 'POST', $endpoint, $accessToken, $options );

$response = $provider->getParsedResponse( $request );
```

The response from the Guzzle request is as follows:

```
{"message":"File cannot be empty","errors":[{"code":"Missing","fields":["document"]}]}
```

It's worth noting I am using the [thephpleague/oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) library to send the request. I'm looking for any discrepencies between the two request or information on how I can troubleshoot this further myself as I have been spinning my wheels all day on this. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**thephpleague/oauth2-client** uses different Providers to create the requests and these Providers implement [AbstractProvider](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/663a45d6c9b9a295fe7e210e650f50e17d6a129f/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php)

The argument **$options** of [AbstractProvider 's getAuthenticatedRequest()](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/663a45d6c9b9a295fe7e210e650f50e17d6a129f/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php)  is different from [GuzzleHttp\Client 's request()](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart):

```
/**
 * Returns an authenticated PSR-7 request instance.
 ...
 * @param  array $options Any of "headers", "body", and "protocolVersion".
 * @return RequestInterface
 */
public function getAuthenticatedRequest($method, $url, $token, array $options = [])
```

Only keys allowed for **$options** are "headers", "body", and "protocolVersion".

You should do the extra effort and **create the headers and body needed**:

```
$file = new \CURLFile( $document );
$file->setPostFilename( basename( $document ) );
$data = array(
    'uploaded_file' => $file
);
$options = array(
    'headers' => array("Content-Type" => "multipart/form-data"),
    'body' => $data
);
$request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest( 'POST', $endpoint, $accessToken, $options );
```

Reference

- [Send file via cURL from form POST in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223977/send-file-via-curl-from-form-post-in-php)