# Is uploading file via FTP faster than HTTP

Tags: android, http, ftp

I have an application on the Android platform with an "*upload file*" feature which uses the HTTP protocol. Unfortunately, sometimes my users decide to upload large files and it takes a very long time to upload all that data.

I just want to improve my app's performance, but I'm not sure if FTP is a faster protocol for file uploads than HTTP.

Does anyone know which protocol is faster?

Comment: No, All things being equal, the speed difference between using FTP and HTTP are insignificant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing HTTP and FTP for transferring files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717200/comparing-http-and-ftp-for-transferring-files)