# Php upload slower than filezilla

Tags: php, linux, apache, upload, centos

I have a web server with centos 6.6 Os, 64GB RAM and php version 5.3.29. If using form post with file the upload speed is 10-20 times slower than when using a FTP client like FileZilla.

**FTP Client**
Upload size : 25Mb.
My home upload mbps : 5 Mb.
Filezilla Upload Kb/S : 600Kib
Upload time : 30 sec.

**Form post upload with Php**
Upload size : 25Mb.
My home upload mbps : 5 Mb.
Php Framework : Codeigniter
Upload time : 57 min.

How I do increase upload speed or how do I configure my server for regular uploads?

Comment: What web server software are you using?

Comment: @Arcturil i am using apache

Comment: From my own experience I know that some hosts have some sort of bottleneck in their network, especially for HTTP requests. Also, in your php.ini, your `post_max_size` setting must be greater than `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717200/comparing-http-and-ftp-for-transferring-files

Comment: @Azarus upload is not associated with php, how i configure mu server/apache for uploads...?

Comment: ReceiveBufferSize?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html